# Use of pointer type

Tags: c, pointers

I'm studying pointer and have had some questions about this.

Pointer type means the size of what address be saved in this pointer has an effect on.

I don't know it is the right expression.

About 2 demensional array,

```
int A[100][100] = {1,2,3,.....} ;
int* x1 = &A;
int* x2 = &A[0];
int* x3 = &A[0][0];
```

In this case, &A,& A[0], &A[0][0] have same address but different size of what these addresses manage.

For example, `&A++` is equal to `address + 4byte * 100 * 100`

`&A[0]++ = address + 4byte * 100`

But, `x1++, x2++, x3++` are all same Incremental value about that expression.
I know this reason is caused by the cast.

Then, what should `i` do for `x1++` will be the same expression as `&A++`?

Comment: The 'address' never manages a memory size, It just points to one single address in memory. What is there depends on (a) the type the pointer is pointing at and (b) you, what you put there in case of malloc. The increment always refers to the type the pointer is of,

Comment: Then, how can i write down the type for x1++ will be the same expression as &A++? It means how can i edit the increment.

Comment: Note you're casting all pointers to the same `int*`...

Comment: @JHBonarius: There are no casts in the code. Casts are explicit operators. There are implicit conversions.

Comment: Turn on warnings in your compiler and pay attention to them. The initializations of `x1` and `x2` violate rules in the C standard, and the compiler is required to diagnose those violations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes of course, I switching languages too often, so mixing up the terminology and concepts.

Answer (score 3):

These variables are not correctly initialized:

```
int* x1 = &A;
int* x2 = &A[0];
```

`&A` is not an `int *`, and neither is `&A[0]`. If you declare `x1` and `x2` properly, you will get the behavior you want when you increment.

```
int (*x1)[100][100] = &A;
int (*x2)[100] = &A[0];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what i want to know.

Answer (score 1):

If `E` is an lvalue expression of type `T`, then `&E` is an expression of type "pointer to `T`" (`T *`).  Remember that an array's size is part of its type - `int [10]` is a different type than `int [11]` or `int [9]`.

The expression `A` has type "one-hundred element array of one-hundred element array of `int`" (`int [100][100]`), so the expression `&A` has type "pointer to 100-element array of 100-element array of `int`" (`int (*)[100][100]`), so `x1` needs to be declared as

```
int (*x1)[100][100] = &A;
```

Similarly, the expression `A[0]` has type "100-element array of `int`" (`int [100]`), so the type of `&A[0]` has type "pointer to 100-element array of `int`" (`int (*)[100]`), so `x2` needs to be declared as

```
int (*x2)[100] = &A[0];
```

Thus, `x1++` will advance to point to the next 100x100 element array following `A`, while `x2++` will advance to point to `A[1]`.

Answer (score -1):

All your pointer are of type `int *`. When you increment them, they will be incremented by `sizeof(int)`.

> Pointer type means the size of what address be saved in this pointer has an effect on.
>   No. Pointer type means type of the object to which the given address points to.

In your code, to move to next element, you need to use following formula:

```
x + (number of columns)*(current row) + row
```

which in your case would be for (i,j)

```
x + 100*i + j
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explaination.